# Find a recurrence relation for bacteria.

Tags: recurrence-relations

I need to find a recurrence relation such that every 2 hours the number of bacteria gets quadrupled and every 4 hours after creation, 3 times as many of the bacteria die. We start with 4 bacteria initially. n = number of hours.
So I'm debating between two relations:

$F(n) = F(n-1) + 4F(n-2) - 3F(n-4)$ or $4F(n-2) - 3F(n-4)$

Any advice on which one? My reasoning for the extra F(n+1) is to take into account the number of bacteria last hour.

Comment: Close duplicate of: [Find the closed form of this Recurrence relation (using repeated substitution) $F(x) = F(x-1) + 4F(x-2) - 3F(x-4)$](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1995182/find-the-closed-form-of-this-recurrence-relation-using-repeated-substitution). If you need to insert additional information, please edit the original question and add it there.

Answer (score 0):

Both recurrence relations are flawed. Look at the pattern: (assumed that the bacteria quadrupled before they died)

$F(0) = 4$

$F(1) = 4$

$F(2) = 16$

$F(3) = 16$

$F(4) = 16 \times 4 - 3 \times 4 = 52$

The number of bacteria isn't necessarily quadrupled everytime. Instead, it quadrupled when $n$ is a multiple of $2$. Hence, the recurrence relation should look like this:

$F(n)=
\begin{cases}
F(n-1)       & \quad \text{if } n \text{ is odd}\\
4F(n-2)-3F(n-4)  & \quad \text{if } n \text{ is divisible by 4}\\
4F(n-2) & \quad \text{if } n \text{ is divisible by 2 but not 4}\\
\end{cases}$